# Need help with Sharepoint foundation web application stuck on "STOPPING" error job-service-instance-GUID Number already exists

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I cant get to stop SharePoint foundation web app service. Its stuck on status stopping
 I have tried the following:

1. reset IIS
2. restarted the Timer Service

When I try to use powershell command to stop I get the following error:

Can anyone who went through this help PLEASE

> Stop-SPServiceInstance : An object of the type
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceInstanceJobDefinition
>   named "job-service-instance-1ff39eb2-12d2-457d-a749-265e350eb1b1"
>   already exists under the parent
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerService named "SPTimerV4". 
>   Rename your object or delete the existing object. At line:1 char:127
>   + ... pplication"} | Stop-SPServiceInstance
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...ServiceInstance:    SPCmdletStopServiceInstance)
>   [Stop-SPServiceInstance], SPDuplicateObjectEx   ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletStopServ    iceInstance

Answer (score 1):

I think I've had simmilar problem. Make sure both SharePoint Timer and Administration services are running.

To get the status with PowerShell:

```
Get-Service sptimerv4, spadminv4
```

Restart services:

```
Get-Service sptimerv4, spadminv4 | ? Status -NE Running | Restart-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

Provision the service and re-start IIS. This was resolved in one of the CU updates. By the way on which SharePoint-CU version you are ?

Comment: Manu when you say provision what do you mean? Any commands to be used?

Comment: Anyone went through this before?

Comment: Refer this URL:http://www.adrit.de/Blog/Post/9/Provisioning-SharePoint-2013-Search-Service-Application-via-PowerShell . This I have used for search service, something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  It seems that the job was not able to be stopped in the original server. It can run on a different app server.  These are the steps that I follow to successfully delete that job

```
#trying to get a list of the SP timer jobs
Get-SPTimerJob | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like "job-service-instance-*"} | Sort-Object Name | Select-Object name, ID, Status
```

Then you get the jobID, and that status that says that it is "online"
when I try to disable it through PS:

```
#this PS "should" disable that timer job, but it doesn't work
Disable-SPTimerJob -Identity "<GUID>"
```

it did nothing.  It keep saying that the job was still **online**. I even went and restart SP timer job, but it did nothing.
I've found this article from TechNet: 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/okoestner/2010/04/28/how-to-delete-a-timer-job-definition

this is the code that I ran:

```
#this code WORKS.!
stsadm.exe -o deleteconfigurationobject -id <GUID>
```

now, I can run the ups [autofixer](https://sharepointbjorn.com/2014/06/25/user-profile-synchronization-autofixer/) from SharePoint Bjorn and get my ups running.

hope this helps someone